# Why I can't access the right scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="project">
   <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{ property1 }}
    <br />
    {{ property2 }}
    <div class="ts" d-child property1="{{ property1 }}cloud" property2="property2">
        property1: {{ property1 }}
        <br />
        property2: {{ property2 }}
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
angular.module('project', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.property1 = 'ss';
    $scope.property2 = 'dd';
});

angular.module('project')
.directive('dChild', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            property1: '@',
            property2: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
//      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="property1" />'
    }
})
```

I thought the `property1: {{ property1 }}` would be "property1: sscloud",but it turns out to be "ss",as if it still refers to the scope of the `mainCtrl` controller, shouldn't it be refer the scope of the `d-child` directive?

if I use template in the directive,it does refer to the right scope and shows 'sscloud',anyone can tell me why?

Comment: nuage , Can you accept my answer

Answer (score 5):

#### When angular compiles an element with isolated scope it has some rules:

- If directives has no template property (or templateUrl), the inner content is attached to the parent scope. Actually before [**this commit**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d0efd5eefcc0aaf167c766513e152b74dd31bafe), inner contents were getting the isolated scope. check your example to confirm it works on versions **less than 1.2**
- If directives do have a template property then it would override the inner content (unless trancluded).
- Only when you use a transclusion, then the inner content is attached to a sibling scope (non isolated).
- The reason why angular works this way is to let reusable components be loosely coupled, and not have any side effects on your application.
- Directives without isolate scope do not get the isolate scope from an isolate directive on the same element ([**see important commit**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7)).
- Directive's template gets the isolated scope anyways.

---

#### If you want to alter this behavior you can pass the isolated scope to the tranclusion function like so:

```
angular.module('project')
.directive('dChild', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,        
        scope: {
            property1: '@',
            property2: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, linker) {
          linker(scope, function(clone, scope){
            element.append(clone)
          })
        }
    }
})
```

#### I highly recommend you to see these tutorials:

- [Angular.js - Transclusion basics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjrBTjMvruI)
- [Angular.js - Components and containers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCiAAr87450)

#### And to read more:

- [Access directive's isolate scope from within transcluded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171952/angularjs-access-directives-isolate-scope-from-within-transcluded-content)
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I really need to dig more in the transclusion function, that is a nice way to be able to use isolated scope in the transcluded html.

Comment: I do not recommend to share the same isolated scope between directives and transcluded contents because it couples the views with directives  which is a bad practice. That is useful only for learning and for hacky solutions.

Comment: Indeed, the fix made in 1.2.x to avoid scope leaking was good. I am just learning the "magic" behind it and this answer was an starting point.

Comment: I can't, I didn't write this question :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about this, I'm pretty sure it all has to do with when each {{}} is evaluated, and when the scope of the directive becomes isolated. My suggestion is to place the content in a template, as it seems to be working when doing so.

If you want to read more about the difference of of "@" and "=" in directive scopes, here's the best text I've found about it.

[What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the `transclude` `option`.
In fact, as `AngularJS` docs says :

```
What does this transclude option do, exactly? transclude makes the contents of 
a directive with this option have access to the scope outside of the directive 
rather than inside.
```

Because of the `Directives` **isolated** `scope` that you created

More docs at:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive